# Looping varlist using rlang

Tags: r, loops, rlang

I'm doing a `for` inside a function using `rlang` but it doesn't work.

#### using r base it works

```
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(R.utils)

db <- tibble(
  CRT1 = 15*rnorm(10),
  CRT2 = 12*rnorm(10))

f <- function(df, controls) {
  for (i in controls) {
    printf("The control variable is %s \n", i)
  }
}

f(tb2, controls = c("CRT1", "CRT2"))

#The control variable is CRT1 
#The control variable is CRT2
```

#### Using rlang

```
f_rlang = function(data, controls){
  
  controls = enquo(controls)
  
  for (i in controls) {
  printf("The control variable is %s \n", i)
  }
}

f_rlang(db, c(CRT1, CRT2))

#Error in for (i in controls) { : invalid for() loop sequence
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if {rlang} itself has a build in functionality to do this, but what you are trying to do mimics the tidy select syntax. So we could use {rlang} together with {tidyselect} to implement this functionality.

This will not only solve your problem, it also adds full tidy select syntax to your function so that we can do `f_rlang(db, starts_with("C"))`:

```r
library(rlang)
library(dplyr)
library(R.utils)

db <- tibble(
  CRT1 = 15*rnorm(10),
  CRT2 = 12*rnorm(10))


f_rlang = function(data, controls){
  
  controls = enexpr(controls)
  
  cols <- tidyselect::eval_select(controls, data)
  
  col_nms <- names(cols)
  
  for (i in col_nms) {
    printf("The control variable is %s \n", i)
  }
}

f_rlang(db, c(CRT1, CRT2))
#> The control variable is CRT1 
#> The control variable is CRT2

f_rlang(db, starts_with("C"))
#> The control variable is CRT1 
#> The control variable is CRT2
```

<sup>Created on 2022-09-30 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Ty @TimTeaFan it works. But why use `enexpr` is there any difference with `enquo` (both work)?. And, why use `names`? "colnames" doesn't work and `rlang::names2` does.

Comment: @cdcarrion  `enquo` captures an environment and an expression, whereas `enexpr()` only captures the later. `tidyselect::eval_select` has an `env` argument which allows to specify where the tidy syntax expression should be evaluated. If we use a quosure then it will automatically use its environment - that is, at least, what the docs say. I couldn't reproduce this behavior and for me it seems there is no difference, but to be safe lets use `enquo`. Regarding the second question: `cols` is a named integer vector. `colnames()` works only on `data.frames` and matrices so we need to use `names()`.